# Convergence of a sequence of definite integrals when the bounds change

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I have begun learning about integral convergence in real analysis, but I have yet to find examples of cases as follows:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{x_{n-1}}^{x_{n}} f_n(x)\,dx$$

That is, for each $n \in \mathbb{N} $, there is a corresponding pair of upper and lower bounds, $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$. Are there techniques to solve such limits? I have not been able to find any, so I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Where does the parameter $T$ live?

Comment: @Vajra I have edited the notation. I hope this is clearer now. I changed $T$ to $n$ to draw a connection with the notation often used in treatments of sequences. Each $n$ just indexes the elements in the sequence.

Comment: You could define a new sequence of functions $g_n(x)=f_n(x)\cdot \chi_{[x_{n-1},x_n]}$ in order to remove the $n$-dependence from tthe domain of integration. Then you study the punctual convergence of $g_n(x)$ in order to apply DCT or MCT.

Comment: Sorry, when you say we can define a new sequence of functions, are you redefining the bounds of the integrals so that they no longer include $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$? I am a bit confused about what your $\chi$ term represents.

Comment: Yep I mean $$\chi_{[x_{n-1},x_n]}(x)=\begin{cases} 1&\text{ if }x\in[x_{n-1},x_n]\\0&\text{ if }x\notin [x_{n-1},x_n]\end{cases}$$

Comment: So, then we would have the following?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} g_n(x)\,dx$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126338/discussion-between-vajra-and-ryan-da-silva).